# Limiting file upload size in jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Does anyone know how to limit the size of uploaded files in jupyterlab?
There is no official solution. Here is the issue presented by others--
https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/5413

But I have to deal with it now.

thanks

Comment: what you did to achieve this?

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet @SPatel

Comment: @sodooo still no solution ?